# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in Reactjs while using onChange while doing todo

Tags: reactjs

```
class Todo extends Component {
state = {
    todo: '',
    todos: [{ id: Math.round(Math.random() * 100), value: '' }]
}

 editchangeHandler = (event, objectid) =>{
            console.log(event.target.value);
            this.setState((prevState)=>({
                todos: prevState.todos.map((todoObjects)=>{
                    if(todoObjects.id == objectid ) {
                        return {value : event.target.value }
                    }
                    return todoObjects
                })
            }))
        }

 renderDataHandler = () => this.state.todos.map((todovalue) => {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value={todovalue.value} className="form-control" onChange={(event)=>this.editchangeHandler(event,todovalue.id)}/>
                    <div>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.editHandler(todovalue.id, todovalue.value)} >Edit</button>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => this.deleteHandler(todovalue.id)}>Delete</button>
                        {/* <button className="btn btn-primary">{todovalue.id}</button> */}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
```

1) I am creating a Todo app

2) editchangeHandler is a method which I am using to edit my todo  In these methods I want to edit my Todo so I want to get  id as well

3) In the setState method, I am looping through all the todos to find the id which matches the id, which I am sending through editHandler method and change the value of that id using event.target.value

Comment: Try: `return {...todoObject,value : event.target.value }` Also if you map objects then the map callback is receiving one object so make todoObjects single: `prevState.todos.map((todoObject)=>{` (removed the s).

Comment: thanks i am trying but i am unable to see change in the input field while onchange (it may be because of linking setstate) how to link the state

Comment: `editchangeHandler = (event, objectid) =>{
        console.log(event.target.value);
         this.state.todos.map((todoobjects) => {
            if(todoobjects.id ==objectid){
                this.setState((prevState)=>({
                   todos: {...todoobjects,value :event.target.value}
            }))` i am getting canot read the proprtey value of null
@HMR

Answer (score 0):

think simple and go step by step. If that works then dive into deeper. I try to give you a simple example below to figure out.

```
editchangeHandler = (event, objectid) =>{
           const wantedTodoIndex = this.state.todos.findIndex(todo => {
               return todo.id === objectid)
           });
           const yourTodos = [...this.state.todos];
           const updateTodo = yourTodos[wantedTodoIndex];
           updateTodo.value = event.target.value;
           yourTodos[wantedTodoIndex] = updateTodo; 
           this.setState({
             todos: yourTodos
           });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the support but think we are going to  ` yourTodos[wantedTodoIndex] = updateTodo; ` these step without completion of previous steps in asyncronus way so we are getting error value of undefined

Answer (score 0):

In my case, When I assigned the value from the event to a local variable. it seemed to work fine.

```
 onChangeUserEmail(e) {
   let updatedEmail = e.target.value;
    this.setState(currentState=>({
        user: {...currentState.user,email:updatedEmail} }
        ))
   }
```

I hope this helps :)